# Error en pyHook KeyboardSwitch()

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy experimentando con un registrador de teclas:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom

def eventoTeclado(event):
        data_key = 'WindowName:'+str(event.WindowName)+ '; Ascii:'+ str(event.Ascii)+" "+ chr(event.Ascii)+ '; Key:'+ str(event.Key)+ '; KeyID:'+ str(event.KeyID)
        print ('WindowName:',event.WindowName)
        print ('Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii))
        print ('Key:', event.Key)
        print ('KeyID:', event.KeyID)
        print ('ScanCode:', event.ScanCode)
        return True
controlador = pyHook.HookManager()
controlador.KeyDown = eventoTeclado
controlador.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

el codigo funciona bien en algunas ventanas, pero por ejemplo en el bloc de notas o google me devuelve:

```
TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'vk_code', 'scan_code', 'ascii', 'flags', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'win_name'
```

¿cómo podría solucionar este error?

Comment: Verifica esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64709/porque-mi-keylogger-en-python-3-6-guarda-espacios-y-no-las-letras-que-registra/72783#72783, saludos.